# CentOS: proftpd не пускает юзеров

Tags: centos7, ftp-сервер

**Всем привет! Есть сервер CentOS с ssh, версия CentOS: release 7.6.1810 (Core), там стоял proftpd. Никак не получалось добавить пользователя для ftp - ftp его не пускал. Когда сменил пароль активному ftp-юзеру, то с новым паролем тоже не получается войти, вернул обратно - тот же результат. 
Я ни фига не сисадмин и сломал уже всю голову себе, что делать? 
**

Вот запрос к ftp: 
https://pastebin.com/CmRywsSb

Конфиг proftpd (proftpd.conf):
https://pastebin.com/UV9zhPvJ

Содержимое файла /etc/pam.d/proftpd
https://pastebin.com/iGB7fMpg

Содержимое файла /etc/nsswitch.conf
https://pastebin.com/3T0URNve

Comment: Как меняли пароль юзеру?

Comment: passwd <имя пользователя>

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу содержимое файла `/etc/pam.d/proftpd`

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас.

Comment: Всё, я добавил.

Comment: Добавьте еще содержимое `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Всё, добавил. Жду.

Comment: Плохие новости - у меня, при прочих равных с вашими конфигами - все работает. Вы уверены, что `proftpd` сейчас обслуживает FTP сервис? Что показывает команда `systemctl status proftpd.service`и команда `ss -ltpn | grep 21` ?

Comment: [root@v142719 /]# sudo systemctl status proftpd.service
● proftpd.service - ProFTPD FTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/proftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-08-16 10:17:35 MSK; 1h 2min ago
  Process: 15461 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/proftpd $PROFTPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15463 (proftpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/proftpd.service
           └─15463 proftpd: (accepting connecti...

Aug 16 10:17:57 v142719.hosted-by-vdsina.ru proftpd[15470]: ...
Aug 16 10:17:57 v142719.hosted-by-vdsina.ru proftpd[15470]

Comment: Кстати с вашим конфигом `proftpd.conf` у меня валится сервис при рестарте. Это как бы не относится к аутентификации, но все же. А у вас команда `systemctl restart proftpd.service` выполняется без ошибок?

Comment: Без ошибок.....

Comment: Тогда я сдаюсь.

Comment: Сейчас проверю.

Comment: Эх, не работает, видемо не судьба мне ftp зделать

Comment: Ваши последние два комментария вижу только я. Их надо было под ответом вставлять.

Answer (score 0):

Подозрение что у пользователя не указан shell. Попробуйте в proftpd.conf добавить
RequireValidShell off.  И перезагрузить proftpd.

Comment: Эх, видемо не судьба мне ftp зделать.